Как в снипете VSCode в переменную добавить имя папки
Как константе добавить имя родительской папки? Как реализовать, чтобы когда я вызывал снипет константе давалось имя родительской папки т.к. файлы компонентов имеют имя index.tsx. Пример компонента DesktopMenu на изображении.


${1:${TM_FILEPATH/.*[\\/\\\\]([^\\/\\\\]+)[\\/\\\\]index\\.(?:t|j)sx?$|.*[\\/\\\\](.*?)(?:\\.[^.]*)$/$1$2/}}

Спасибо, все заработало
